# Is EPSG defined separately for each geometry column?

Tags: postgis

I know SRID is defined separately for each geometry column, but

Is EPSG defined separately for each geometry column as well or is EPSG same across the database? Also, how do I find the EPSG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, [EPSG](https://epsg.org/home.html) is the name of a catalog of projection, that assign a number for each projection, to simplify the handling of them. The SRID is the parameter that contain the projection for a given geom field.

You can set or get the SRID for a field using its EPSG number or another referential recognized by PostGIS (I think you can even add your own, if you set the mathematical parameters). So if you get the SRID of a field, it will usually be a number that correspond to an entry of the EPSG catalog. PostGIS store a list of all the SRID it recognize in the table spatial_ref_sys.

Comment: epsg.io despite the name is not the official registry, the official EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset is epsg.org

Answer (score 8):

PostGIS keeps its spatial reference system info in a table called `spatial_ref_sys` which you can query and is created in the source code with several megs of SQL that starts like this:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "spatial_ref_sys" ("srid", "auth_name", "auth_srid", "srtext", "proj4text") VALUES
--
-- EPSG 2000 : Anguilla 1957 / British West Indies Grid 
--
(2000, 'EPSG', 2000, 'PROJCS["Anguilla 1957 / British West Indies Grid",GEOGCS["Anguilla 1957",DATUM["Anguilla_1957",SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 (RGS)",6378249.145,293.465,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7012"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6600"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4600"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-62],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9995],PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2000"]]', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-62 +k=0.9995000000000001 +x_0=400000 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk80 +units=m +no_defs '),
--
```

From https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/spatial_ref_sys.sql

EPSG code lookups are done with reference to this table, eg the `auth_name` of "EPSG" and an `auth_code` of "3857" will be the same for all spatial tables in a single database. If you mess with this table you can probably break your data in all sorts of horrible ways, so don't!

The `srid` column here is the one that links to your spatial data, so that is  a unique index (unlike `auth_srid`, since different authorities may use the same numbers for different coordinate systems).

So you can find the EPSG code of a spatial table by matching on the `srid` and then checking that the `auth_name` is "EPSG" (other authorities exist).